# Convert rotation matrix between coordinate systems?

Tags: linear-algebra

let say there are two orthonormal coordinate systems $A,B$ related by linear map $T$:

$$T \vec{v_A}=\vec{v_B}\qquad\forall\ \vec{v_A}\in A,\ \vec{v_B}\in B$$

Now if we have a rotation matrix $R_A$ represented in $A$, how to obtain the corresponding $R_B$ represented in $B$?

I suspect a dirty way is convert $R_A$ to angle-axis then map the axis to $B$ and convert back to matrix:

$$\textbf{R}(\theta,\hat{n_A}):=R_A$$

$$R_B = \textbf{R}(\theta,\hat{n_B}) = \textbf{R}(\theta,T\hat{n_A})$$

Is it correct?

Are there other ways that use only matrix, like $R_B = XR_A$ ?

Comment: Are you working in a linear space with a specific dimension?

Comment: @somebody4 You can try conjugation with $T$ right?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net only 3D

Comment: @DeepakMS what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{v_a \}_{a \in A}$ and $\{v_b \}_{b\in B}$ are two bases (coordinate systems) of the same space and they are related by $T$ as you mentioned, then the rotation in basis $B$ is given by :
$$R_B = T R_A T^{-1} $$

Comment: Thanks, are there proof available online?

Comment: Is it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class ?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I somehow missed this comment/forgot to reply. You probably already found this by now, but still. This article mentions this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis